# How to synchronize odoo database with another odoo database?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

I have two databases in my postgesql, one for the client and another one for the administration, we have these legal texts created in the administration database. What I need to do is to create a button "synchronize" in the client side to allow him to add new legal texts (if there is new legal texts) to his database. I don't know how to do it, or how to access another database from the current one.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Working from the premise that your legal texts are in postgresql tables. What exactly are you asking:
- how to add a button to an Odoo form?- How to access another database from within Odoo code?
- How to synchronise tables from two databases?

Comment: How to synchronise tables from two databases..

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at this page Web service api odoo provid you with a couple of webservice allow you to performe search or read data or create or update almost everything you need in here so if you want to create some record in the other odoo instance use xml-rpc and you can create or update anything you want if you have acces rights.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html

read it carefully it's so easy to understand and the example works fine in the online version you need it